# Why are the limits equal when $n$ approaches infinity?

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital, infinity

I have the following question:

> **7.** If $x_1=3$ and $x_{n+1}=\sqrt{2+x_n}$, $n\ge1$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n$ is
>
> (1) $-1$
>
> (2) 2
>
> (3) $\sqrt 5$
>
> (4) 3

And I found this solution for it:

> **7. (2)** $x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+x_n}$ 
> or $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n}$ 
> or $t=\sqrt{2+t}$ $\displaystyle \left( \because \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = t \right)$ 
> or $t^2-t-2=0$ 
> or $(t-2)(t+1)=0$ 
> or $t=2$ $(\because x_n>0 \ \forall \ n,t>0)$

But how can we say that these two limits are equal when $n$ approaches to infinity as we can’t compare infinity?

Comment: Please do not use pictures or links to pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1} $? If so, add this to your question

Comment: Think about what is the meaning of the existence of a finite limit.

Comment: The step $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = \lim_{n\to\infty} x_{n+1}$ is not about comparing infinities (there are some infinities that are greater than others, but rather about making $x_n$ to converge one step faster.

Comment: Can you please explain it more elaborately with an example please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, we need to proof that this sequence is convergent.
$$X_1 = 3 \space \text{and} \space X_{n+1} = \sqrt{2+X_n}, n \ge 1.$$
We are going to use **Monotone Convergence Theorem**. If you see Elementary Real Analysis, Bartle, 4th ed, page 71. It says

**A sequence is convergence if and only if monotone and bounded**.

First we are going to proof the sequence is monotone by induction.
It is clear that
$$X_2 = \sqrt{2+3} < \sqrt{9}=X_1.$$
So we have some intuition, *this sequence is decreasing*.
If $X_{n+1} < X_n$, then
$$X_{n+2} = \sqrt{2+x_{n+1}} < \sqrt{2+X_{n}} = X_{n+1}.$$
So that the sequence is decreasing.

We all know that this sequence is bounded by $0$.

We have proven that the sequence is monotone and bounded. So the sequence is convergent.

Let $a$ is the limit of $X_n$. That is
$$a = \lim_{n \to \infty} X_n.$$
So that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} X_{n+1} = a.$$

We have
$$a = \sqrt{2+a} \Longleftrightarrow a^2-a-2 = 0 \Longleftrightarrow (a-2)(a+1) = 0.$$
Finally
$$a = 2 \vee a = -1.$$
Because of the sequence is bounded by $0$, so it must be positive sequence. We choose $2$ as a limit of the sequence.

If you are worry about the step of *comparing at infinity*, see
$$X_n = \frac{1}{n}, \space \text{so that} \space X_{n+1} = \frac{1}{n+1}.$$
The limit
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} = 0.$$
And so does
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1} = 0 = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{n}.$$